# Why does System.runAs consumes two DML rows

Tags: apex

[Using the runAs Method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm) in test class is a best practices compared inserting users.

But `System.runAs` seems to be consuming 2 DML statements and rows; where as `insert users` consumes 1. Isn't that weird, why twice?

Here is the test class to replicate the behavior:

```
@IsTest 
private class UserTest {

    static testMethod void test_runAs(){

        User user = createTestUser(null, UserInfo.getProfileId(), 'Raul', 'S');

        Test.startTest();

        System.runAs(user){
            System.assertNotEquals(null, user.Id);
        }

        // fails as its consumes 2 DML statements and rows
        System.assertEquals(1, System.Limits.getDMLStatements());

        Test.stopTest();


    }

    static testMethod void test_insertUser(){

        User user = createTestUser(null, UserInfo.getProfileId(), 'Raul', 'S');

        Test.startTest();

        insert user;
        System.assertNotEquals(null, user.Id);
        // passes
        System.assertEquals(1, System.Limits.getDMLStatements());

        Test.stopTest();

    }

    // generate unique user instance
    public static User createTestUser(Id roleId, Id profID, String fName, String lName) {
        String orgId = UserInfo.getOrganizationId();
        String dateString = 
            String.valueof(Datetime.now()).replace(' ','').replace(':','').replace('-','');
        Integer randomInt = Integer.valueOf(math.rint(math.random()*1000000));
        String uniqueName = orgId + dateString + randomInt;
        User tuser = new User(  firstname = fName,
                                lastName = lName,
                                email = uniqueName + '@test' + orgId + '.org',
                                Username = uniqueName + '@test' + orgId + '.org',
                                EmailEncodingKey = 'ISO-8859-1',
                                Alias = uniqueName.substring(18, 23),
                                TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
                                LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
                                LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
                                ProfileId = profId,
                                UserRoleId = roleId);
        return tuser;
    }

}
```

---

DML statement limit consumed for `test_runAs` method:

```
10:41:50:000 LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS   Number of DML statements: 2 out of 150
10:41:50:000 LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS   Number of DML rows: 2 out of 10000
```

Comment: I'd guess one to change the user and one to change it back at the end of the runAs block.

Comment: Did you run all the tests from this class or any specific one? Specify if one.

Comment: @rahul gawale: Please look at the Number of DML statements or DML rows. AFAIK even if we run the test methods together, they are isolated. Running them independently yields same result.

Comment: Interesting point, thanks @Phil W

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`System.runAs()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm) counts itself as a DML statement:

> Every call to runAs counts against the total number of DML statements issued in the process.

This is probably analogous to, e.g., `Database.setSavepoint()` and other calls that manipulate the transaction.

It also performs an *implicit insert* of the selected user if that user is not already inserted.  `createTestUser()` here does not insert the user object, so it's inserted when `runAs()` is called, consuming a second DML statement.

Comment: Thanks David, that makes sense!